# Ajax post and get checkbox value

Tags: php, ajax, post, checkbox

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function processForm() { 
$.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/checkbox.php?name=foton',
    data: { checked_box : $('input:checkbox:checked').val()},

    success: function(data) {
        $('#message').html(data);
    }
} );
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="foton" value="1" onclick="processForm()">
```

checkbox.php file:

```
    $checkbox = intval($_POST['foton']);

if($checkbox == 1){
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET sekretessFoton = 1 WHERE userID = $memberID");
}else{
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET sekretessFoton = 0 WHERE userID = $memberID");    
}
```

The problem is that i dont get any value from $_POST['foton']
What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your code in:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/checkbox.php',
    data: { foton : $('input:checkbox:checked').val()},

    success: function(data) {
        $('#message').html(data);
    }
} );
```

```
/ajax/checkbox.php?name=foton
```

Here you have a `$_GET` parameter that's called `name` and its **value** is `foton`.

In my code you're sending the value of your checkbox in a `$_POST` **parameter** called `foton`.

You don't have to set a query string in your `$.ajax` url when you specify data (instead of you **want** to redirect to a page which will process your `$_GET` parameters a part).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a POST varible that isn't defined or sent.

Try

```
$checkbox = intval($_POST['checked_box']);
```

In you ajax you are sending data as `checked_box`. Also you are not posting any thing else this checked box value. The only other value that you are sending is through query string `?name=foton` which could be accessed via `$_GET['name']`. I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

You have post ajax with this:

```
data: { checked_box : $('input:checkbox:checked').val()},
```

here  checked_box is the name of your parameter. you need to get value by this name.

Try this:

```
$checkbox = intval($_REQUEST['checked_box']);
```