# send checkbox value with ajax to php

Tags: ajax

send checkbox value in ajax.

The check box value is not getting posted to php, the whole script is not working after this.
Please can some one tell me where i am making the mistake and provide me a solution for this.

```
function ajaxFunction(str,str1,str2,str3)
        {
            var security = $('input[name="subfolder"]').prop('checked');
            var httpxml;
            try
            {
// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e)
            {
// Internet Explorer
                try
                {
                    httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e)
                    {
                        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            function stateChanged()
            {
                if(httpxml.readyState==4)
                {
                    document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;

                }
            }


            var url="my-test-search.php";
            url=url+"?txt="+str+"&txt1="+str1+"&txt2="+str2+"&txt3="+str3+"&che="+security;
            url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
            httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
            httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
            httpxml.send(null);
        }



  <form id="myform" method="post">
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Search : <input type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" size="44" >
                    Extension : <input type="text" id="search_extension" name="search_extension" size="4" maxlength="4"> <br><br>
                                  Include Sub Files <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder" name="subfolder" value="0">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                   LTO-No. <input type="text" id="search_ltono" name="search_ltono" size="4" maxlength="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input name="buttonExecute" onclick="ajaxFunction(search_text.value,search_ltono.value,search_extension.value,subfolder.value)" type="button" value="Show&nbsp;&nbsp;" />

                        </form>
```

Comment: Please Try This Link:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164884/ajax-post-and-get-checkbox-value)

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox is not have an attribute value, but have attribute checked. Try to use:

```
subfolder.checked
```

and drop attribute value from your markup

Comment: Still not working. if i remove this line  var security = $('input[name="subfolder"]').prop('checked'); the script works but i want checkbox value to be sent to php.