# How do I make my database update a value when a checkbox is checked in my table { AJAX }

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

I'm wanting to make my code so that when I click in the checkbox to enable it, it updates a row in my database to the value 1. My checkbox is inside of my table in php and is coded around AJAX. My issue is that when I click the checkbox, 1) it doesn't do anything, (not even refresh the page using my ajax success status) : `

```
success: function(data) {
   window.location.replace("admin_members.php");
}
```

2) It doesn't update my database information giving my column named 'enabled' a value of 1 for when it's checked from the PHP receiver.

***My Code is Below :***

**Html / PHP Table (checkbox is included in here)**

```
<td style="border: 1px solid #eee; text-align: center; font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'enabled','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["enabled"]  == 1 ? '<input id="enabled-checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox" checked >' : '<input id="enabled-checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox" >'; ?></td>
```

**AJAX Sender**

```
        function showEdit(editableObj) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
        } 

        function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url('images/spin.gif') no-repeat right");
            $.ajax({
                url: "includes/saveedit_members.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    window.location.replace("admin_members.php");
                }        
           });
        }
```

**PHP Receiver**

```
if(!isset($_POST['column']) || !isset($_POST["editval"]) || !isset($_POST["id"])) {
    header('Location: error-pages/index.php');
} else if(isset($_POST['column']) && isset($_POST["editval"]) && isset($_POST["id"])) {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users set " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);
}
```

**A few picture examples to help understand my database and why I'm trying to do :**

[I want it so if the checkbox is checked, automatically refresh page after updating database column 'enabled' to 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgWcF.png)

Comment: I don't see a database query where you are updating a table named `enabled`

Comment: @Maximus2012 oh yes. I have now updated it :)

Comment: Are you sure the control is going to your AJAX PHP page ? According to your logic, it should either set the value to 1 or 0 so at least one of the queries must be getting executed.

Comment: @Maximus2012 i don't think it is going to my AJAX page becuase I even tried just showing a simple alert('Hello'); and it didnt't output anything. The error I think is https://gyazo.com/f5867784f2e1ce903b469004ff5b012c that you have to click in / on the value of the white space where the data is then click out of it to make it update. When i check a checkbox inside there, it just stays checked without refreshing the page because i didn't click in the white space. If you understand ?

Comment: I think you should update your question with the code for your AJAX request. Are you using jQuery ? You should also use the SO image upload option to make that image a part of your original question to make it more visible.

Comment: @Maximus2012 i have now added my ajax code that sends the commands.

Comment: I think you need to bind the AJAX code to the checkbox checked event. Not sure if your code is doing that. Something like this maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164884/ajax-post-and-get-checkbox-value
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365311/ajax-checkboxes-with-jquery-and-php

Comment: @Maximus2012 Although this one is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164884/ajax-post-and-get-checkbox-value . It doesn't fix my problem. I need it to update the database as soon as I check the checkbox too.

Comment: If you do it right then the AJAX/PHP code will take care of the database update. Looks like your problem is that the request is not even going to the PHP code. You might need to fix that first. Also, looking at the image that you posted and also your code, you might need an array of checkboxes with the checkbox id/value containing the information about the row that you want to update in the database.

Comment: you have the bind the savetodatabase() function to the checkbox cheched/unchecked event, not sure if you are doing that.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I'm now trying to do this : `<td style="border: 1px solid #eee; text-align: center; font-size: 11px;"><?php echo $faq[$k]["enabled"]  == 1 ? '<input name="enabled_checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,"enabled",$faq[$k]["id"];)" onClick="showEdit(this);" checked >':'<input name="enabled_checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,"enabled",$faq[$k]["id"];)" onClick="showEdit(this);">'; ?></td>` but it now does not update or refresh the page. It does nothing.

Comment: I think it's probably better if you update your question with this additional information. It would make it easier for the users here to assist you.

Comment: I am not sure if using onblur function is the best way to go or if it is even working. You might want to bind the checkbox to a checked event via jQuery/AJAX like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017558/checkbox-checked-or-unchecked-with-jquery-and-mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event

Comment: @Maximus2012 I have now updated it, is that more helpful ?

Comment: Yes but i don't think that's where your problem is. You might want to look at the SO questions/answers that I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I have. None of them have helped me understand. It works without a checkbox becuase of the `data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,` inner html part. A checkbox doesn't have html inner text. Just a value.

Comment: Are you sure that your AJAX request is getting through ? Are you able to pass the data to the PHP code ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 without the checkbox, yes. If I take out the checkbox, it updates my database with the value I type in for example, 1. Using this : `mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users set " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);` in the PHP receive

Comment: So you need to make sure that on the checkbox checked/unchecked event,  there is an AJAX request being sent to the PHP code, which is what some of those questions are about.

Comment: @Maximus2012 can you not help me directly? According to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it now :) After hard work.